# Structurizing data in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, database

I have recently started to use Firebase. However, since I am not familiar with NoSQL databases I am having a little trouble structurizing it.

I am developing a timesheet application, several users can input their starting and ending hours each day they go to work and it will be saved into a database.

At the moment the structure of my firebase looks like this :

[image: http://imgur.com/tnojU8x]

However, I am having some trouble accessing this data in my application. On top of that this just doesn't feel right. First I wanted to just add a new entry under 'timesheet' every time a user inputs something, but obviously, I do not want a user to be able to add 2 entries for one day either.

I know that there's probably some complex way to stop a user from doing this, but I feel that this could all be solved in an easier way if I just saw how I should best structure this database.

Later I want to loop through all the days in the current month for a specific user to show him in a table all his starting/ending hours for each day of the month.

Update: I was thinking about denormalizing my database, but would that really help anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), written by the Firebase team.

TL;DR is that you *should* denormalize your data because Firebase is optimized for certain kinds of operations (you don't need to fully understand the nitty gritty of that optimization to use Firebase properly).

#### "I am having some trouble accessing this data in my application"

What kind of trouble?

#### "I do not want a user to be able to add 2 entries for one day either."

That isn't really a denormalization problem; with your structure now, you could just check a path for null.

`new Firebase('path/to/timesheets/April/'+ queryDate) === null`, where queryDate is the date you want to check for.

If the above returns true, your user hasn't submitted a timesheet. If so, you shouldn't allow them to.

#### "I want to loop through all the days in the current month for a specific user to show him in a table all his starting/ending hours for each day of the month."

You can! Iterate with a for loop through all the values nested under the object that's returned when you ask for `new Firebase("path/to/April")`.